# PDFBox 2.0.3 Set cropBox using TextPosition coordinates

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I've located a region of interest in the page by tracking `TextPosition` objects using `PDFTextStripper` as shown in the example: https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintTextLocations.java

As shown, the TextPosition has been retrieved from fields like
`text.getXDirAdj()`, `text.getWidthDirAdj()`, `text.getYDirAdj()`, `text.getHeightDir()` .

From this example I tried to keep everything else the same except setting the cropBox of the target page.

https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/2.0.3/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/PDFToImage.java

OLD CROPBOX: [0.0,0.0,595.276,841.89] -> NEW CROPBOX [50.0,42.0,592.0,642.0].

So how can I use the `getYDirAdj` and `getXDirAdj` in setting the cropbox correctly ?

The original pdf file I'm processing can be downloaded from here: http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201504/20150407095631744/ENG-US_NMATSCJ-1.103-0330.pdf

Comment: Please show the code you used and post a link to source and result pdf.

Comment: Please be aware that the PDFBox text extraction favors a different coordinate system from the default user space coordinate system used for the page boxes. To retrieve user space coordinates, use `getTextMatrix().getTranslateX()` and `getTextMatrix().getTranslateY()`

Comment: I've seen how from an BufferedImage, one can create a Graphics2D object, rotate it according to the affine transformation and then draw on it objects.
I managed to manually fiddle with cropbox coordinates and got some parts of the image visible but I still cannot figure out what transformation I need to apply to the rectangle containing the text I want extracted to match the cropbox. PDRectangle is a beast

Secondly, its not very clear to me when I need to transform the coordinates and what is the procedure that takes me from one realm to another. I would appreciate if you can clarify this.

Comment: "All the pages end up white even thought the new crop box" - they are not white. I suspect your link is the original file.

Comment: Re all the transformations, have a look at the DrawPrintTextLocations.java example in the source code download.

Comment: Use also PDFDebugger to show a page and position the mouse cursor. At the bottom left it will show you the PDF coordinates. So you can see where (46.0,501.0) and (588.0,701.0). Note also that pages are zero based. So your page 12 in the code is page 13 in the PDF.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.
Yes, the link is the original PDF file I'm trying to process. The image I save to disk is white.
Re page number, page 12 (as shown in the debugger or Acrobat reader) is retrieved as `val page = doc.getPage(pageNum - 1)`.

Comment: I've seen `DrawPrintTextLocations` but doesn't solve my problem. There you have the Graphics2D which you push through AffineTransformation so you can draw on it using `TextLocation` coordinates.

If I have a PDRectangle created using `TextLocation` coordinates, what transformation are needed to be applied to the rect so I can pass it as argument to setCropBox ?

Comment: So I have used the debugger and eyeballed a good box on page with index=11. My code below produces a white jpg image:
    `val newCB = new PDRectangle(40f, 680f, 510f, 100f)` + 
    `page.setCropBox(newCB)`

Comment: The problem is that I can't fix your program as you're using scala and I'm not, your program is not self-working, so the best I can do is to point you to something that may or may not help. Cropbox coordinates have the y=0 at the bottom. text.getYDirAdj() has the y=0 at the top so you need to substract it from the cropbox height.

Comment: Ok. Given a java `PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle(40f, 680f, 510f, 100f)` obtained from `TextLocation` how would a java code snippet, that sets the cropBox of a single page look like ? Or how would you do it? `TextLocation` based rect --> some transformation --> `setCropBox(theRightBox)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Cropping the page

In a comment the OP reduced his problem to

> Ok. Given a java `PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle(40f, 680f, 510f, 100f)` obtained from `TextLocation` how would a java code snippet, that sets the cropBox of a single page look like ? Or how would you do it? `TextLocation` based rect --> some transformation --> `setCropBox(theRightBox)`.

To set the crop box of the page twelve of the given document to the given `PDRectangle` you can use code like this:

```
PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(resource);
PDPage page = pdDocument.getPage(12-1);
page.setCropBox(new PDRectangle(40f, 680f, 510f, 100f));
pdDocument.save(new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "ENG-US_NMATSCJ-1.103-0330-page12cropped.pdf"));
```

*([SetCropBox.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/meta/SetCropBox.java#L42) test method `testSetCropBoxENG_US_NMATSCJ_1_103_0330`)*

Adobe Reader now shows merely this part of page twelve:

[image: Screenshot]

Beware, though, the page in question does not only specify a media box (mandatory) and a crop box, it also defines a bleed box and an art box. Thus, application which consider those boxes more interesting than the crop box, might display the page differently. In particular the art box (being defined as "the extent of the page’s meaningful content") might by some applications be considered important.

#### Rendering the cropped page

In a comment to this answer the OP remarked

> This is good and works. It correctly saves the page in the PDF file. I've tried to do the same in JPG and failed.

I reduced the OP's code to the essentials

```
PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(resource);
PDPage page = pdDocument.getPage(12-1);
page.setCropBox(new PDRectangle(40f, 680f, 510f, 100f));

PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(pdDocument);
BufferedImage img = renderer.renderImage(12 - 1, 4f);
ImageIOUtil.writeImage(img, new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "ENG-US_NMATSCJ-1.103-0330-page12cropped.jpg").getAbsolutePath(), 300);
pdDocument.close();
```

*([SetCropBox.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/meta/SetCropBox.java#L66) test method `testSetCropBoxImgENG_US_NMATSCJ_1_103_0330`)*

The result:

[image: Result image]

Thus, I cannot reproduce an issue here.

---

Possible details to check for:

- `ImageIOUtil` is not part of the main PDFBox artifact, instead it is located in *pdfbox-tools*; does the version of that artifact match the version of the core *pdfbox* artifact?
- I run the code in an Oracle Java 8 environment; other Java environments might give rise to different results.
- There are minor differences in our implementations. E.g. I load the PDF via an `InputStream`, you directly from file system, I have hardcoded the page number, you have it in some variable, ... None of these differences should cause your problem, but who knows...

Comment: Ok. This is good and works. It correctly saves the page in the PDF file.
I've tried to do the same in JPG and failed. The code is in JAVA in this gist :
https://gist.github.com/vicpara/e4bc953424dde64f60f1c4f1af3f8a95

Comment: The local file must have been altered in my previous attempts to get this working. Loading the file from remote URL showed the correct behaviour. Sorry for the hassle but the framework works correctly. +1 Thanks!